# trying to update a query with two possible where functions

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

Kwame has sold $55,000 worth of products this week. Write a query which updates his sales to reflect this.

This is what I have so far:

```
UPDATE Salesmen SET Sales=55000 WHERE Salesman=Kwame
```

Other columns include:

- SalesYear
- Sales
- Salary
- Region
- BonusLevel

Answer (score 1):

Given the other columns I would add criteria for salesyear to make sure you're updating the row representing the correct year, and change 55,000 to be the current value plus that amount, rather than just that amount, like so:

```
UPDATE Salesmen
   SET Sales = sales + 55000
 WHERE Salesman = 'Kwame'
   and salesyear = 2014
```